# Twitter Api Python Connection stalled error

Tags: python, twitter

I am using TwitterAPI python library and while fetching data its giving this error

```
File "/Users/danny/.venv/versions/2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/TwitterAPI/TwitterAPI.py", line 263, in _iter_stream
    raise TwitterConnectionError('Twitter stream stalled')
TwitterConnectionError: Twitter stream stalled
```

I am using python 2.7

Comment: Read the documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/connecting). There is a section about *stalls*. That should give you information about what you are experiencing. Looking up the exception will lead to several links that give information on that exception to provide context on why that is happening.

Comment: @idjaw ok thanks let me check them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stalls are something to be expected and you must account for them (and other types of connection errors) in your twitter client. The [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) library does check for stalls. When they occur a `TwitterConnectionError` is thrown. This is a signal to you to simply retry your request. You don't need to set a 90-second timer. This is done for you by TwitterAPI. In order to achieve truly robust code you should also handle the `TwitterRequestError`. Here is a template for dealing with both exceptions in order to keep your code running and staying within Twitter's guidelines:

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
api = TwitterAPI(CONSUMER_KEY,
                 CONSUMER_SECRET,
                 ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
                 ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

while True:
    try:
        iterator = api.request('statuses/filter', {'track':'pizza'}).get_iterator()
        for item in iterator:
            if 'text' in item:
                print(item['text'])
            elif 'disconnect' in item:
                event = item['disconnect']
                if event['code'] in [2,5,6,7]:
                    # something needs to be fixed before re-connecting
                    raise Exception(event['reason'])
                else:
                    # temporary interruption, retry request
                    break
    except TwitterRequestError as e:
        if e.status_code < 500:
            # something needs to be fixed before re-connecting
            raise
        else:
            # temporary interruption, retry request
            pass
    except TwitterConnectionError:
        # temporary interruption, retry request
        pass
```

Comment: @Jones can you include complete code with reconnect part

Comment: Except for the imports and entering your Twitter keys the code is complete. You can re-use your code for this. But in case that is not clear see [this example](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/stream_tweets.py). The reconnect part is there -- see the `while` loop -- the request will re-run because of the `pass` statement.

Comment: The example code is now complete. Just supply your keys and it should work.